# How to make sure the label's for attribute references the correct id of a form field in Angular 16

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

**The problem:**
I keep on getting errors on chrome about incorrectly using label.

The error reads:

> Incorrect use of
>
> The label's for attribute doesn't match any element id. This might prevent the browser from correctly autofilling the form and accessibility tools from working correctly.
>
> To fix this issue, make sure the label's for attribute references the correct id of a form field.
>
> 5 resources

The 5 resources points to each  present on the page.

[The error showing up on chrome 114.0.5735.110, using angular 16. package is shown below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZY03.png)

**I have tried**:

- adding the id attribute to  element so the "for" attribute matches the "id" attribute of the form field.
- Only having the formControlName="company" in .
- removing the "for" in the label, but keeping "id" in .
- using the "[for]" attribute binding instead of the "for" attribute.
- using  instead of  which creates a different issues rather than fixing it.
- using aria-labelledby="company" in
- using attr.for, that just tells me to use "for".
- using floatLabel="always" in the .

All of these attempts to fixing the problem resulted in the same error as above. However, the page seems to work fine with those errors. Regardless, I'd like to fix them now if possible.

Here's single example of the 5  I have in my html file. Not showing the whole file, just the problem part.

```
<form [formGroup]="createEntry" class="form">
    <h4>complete-inspection</h4>
    <mat-form-field class="select">
        <mat-label for="company">company</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="company" id="company">
            <mat-option value="test">test</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

I have tried other forms such as an input which does not produce the error Incorrect use of :

```
<mat-form-field class="select">
    <mat-label>company</mat-label>
    <input formControlName="company" type="text" matInput>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here are my imports and my form group for the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { QuestionService } from '../question.service';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

export class CompleteInspectionComponent implements OnInit {
  
  public createEntry: FormGroup = new FormGroup({})
  public templates: Template[] = [];
  public templateQuestions: TemplateQuestions[] = [];
  public equipmentTypeTemplates: Template[] = [];
  public templateRevision: number = 0;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private _questionService: QuestionService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Anything that does not need to be in the form group can be changed into a class attribute
    this.createEntry = this.fb.group({
      company: [''],
      templateID: [''],
      templateRevision: [''],
      questionIDs: this.fb.array([]),
      employeeID: [''],
      equipment: [''],
      equipmentType: [''],
      answers: this.fb.array([]),
      answerComments: this.fb.array([]),
      answerDates: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "inspection",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~5.0.2"
  }
}
```

With all that said, is there something that I am missing to reference the elements correctly? How do I make sure the label's for attribute references the correct id of a mat-select and stop having this error.

*I'm trying to only show what my problem is to reduce clutter, not the whole code and files.

Comment: mat-angular create the label for to a div element, that it's not a ["labeable" element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#form-associated_content). You can [open an issue](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/issues) in material-angular if you want.

Comment: There is already an issue on [github](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/27241)